# chequear un objeto null javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Hola estoy comenzando el javascript, tengo una json con varios campos entre esos previo pero previo es un objeto, hice la consulta pero no me lo valida....trae de igual cuando previo es null

```
async function ListaconCondicionProceso(lista) {


    return new Promise(resolve => {


        const ListaFiltrada = lista.map(item => {
            var diferencia = moment(hoy, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").local().diff(moment(item.createdAt, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").local(), 'hours');
            if (diferencia >= horasLimites && item!== null && item.previo!==null ) {
                        return item
            }
        })
            resolve (ListaFiltrada)
    }
    )
}
```

igual trae la lista cuando el objeto previo es null.. de antemano gracias....

Comment: Una funcion asincrona siempre retorna una promesa sea que tu retornes una promesa o no retornes nada dentro de la función, y en tu caso estas retornando una promise dentro de otra promise que será la que siempre retorne tu función asincrona, ademas estas comprobando de menera correcta que sea diferente de null, pero no estas comprobando si enrealidad diferencia tiene contenido, que tal si primero miras que hay en diferencia?, si no hay contenido es por eso que te devuelve null.

Comment: Lo otro es que supongo que ya sabes como ejecutar una promesa, por que ellas no se ejecutan solas...

Comment: Gracias, si mando a ejecutar la promesa, pero tanto diferencia como item.previo tienen datos, pero entonces que sentencia podria colocar dentro de la promesa para que solo me retorne cuando cumpla con la condicion..????

Comment: Estas retornando sobre map, no sobre la promesa, la promesa como tal le estas diciendo que siempre retorne ListaFiltrada, aunque enrealidad porque no usar la promesa de todas maneras? es decir, si te retorna null entonces siempre lo que puedes hacer a tu favor es usar ese null para comprobar si hay datos o no desde la promesa, o tambien comprobar primero si tu ListaFiltrada tiene datos (que su length sea mayor a 0), y si quieres una mejor comprobación no uses map, usa filter.

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo y por escribirme, riven pero honestamente no entiendo como hacer la estructura estoy comensando y no tengo muchos conocimientos sobre el tema....igual gracias muy amable por tu tiempo

Comment: Es que no te doy una respuesta por que no tengo esos datos que usas como para poder recrear tu problema... y ademas las funciones moment y local hasta donde se no son propias de js a lo mejor estas usando un framework que no mencionas, por lo de las funciones siempre se puede importar el framework para darte una respuesta, pero si no hay información que reproduzca el problema, nosotros no podremos darte una solución... no necesariamente toda la información pero si la minima que nos ayude a reproducir el problema. por ejemplo lo que contiene lista.

Comment: Gracias igual por tu tiempo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se si esto es lo que deseas pero aquí un mismo ejemplo con filter:

```
async function ListaconCondicionProceso(lista) {

    const ListaFiltrada = lista.filter(item => {
        var diferencia = moment(hoy, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").local().diff(moment(item.createdAt, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").local(), 'hours');

        if(diferencia){
            if (diferencia >= horasLimites && item!== null && item.previo!==null ) {
                return item;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    })

    return ListaFiltrada;

}

ListaconCondicionProceso(lista).then(res =>{
    console.log(res);
});
```

La diferencia entre `filter` y `map` es que filter solo te va a meter dentro de un array los elementos que cumplan con una condición, mientras que map, itera por todos y puedes hacer transformaciones de elementos dentro del, es decir, modificar el valor de retorno.

Sin embargo con map, siempre llegaras a tener una lista del mismo tamaño que el tamaño del arreglo original, mientras que con filter esto no necesariamente es así. puedes llegar a tener 0 elementos con filter si la condición nunca se cumple.

Comment: Riven honestamente muchas gracias por tu tiempo disuclpa tanta molestia....el codigo me fuciono perfectamente....disculpa mi ignoracia....